# What is the point of hashes when downloading over the same channel?

Tags: file-upload

What is the point of providing shaXXX hashes for downloads of software over say TLS when any attacker that could change the download could have easily changed the hash? Isn't there enough information in the download to know that it is corrupt? Just seems brain dead to me.

Comment: Prob dupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/does-hashing-a-file-from-an-unsigned-website-give-a-false-sense-of-security and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111895/why-are-there-hashes-next-to-downloads

Answer (score 1):

Correct, if the hash is provided on the website next to the download then it does nothing. If the hash is provided over a separate channel, especially if something reliably archives the hash that was published when the binary was published, then it provides some security. Not as much security as a digital signature, but some.

So hashes published in archives of mailing lists, hashes you received by email directly, hashes in package manager manifests, etc. are useful.